# android shape does not change size

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

Please help me for a layout on Android.

**flat_btn_hover.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#f45d5d"
        android:centerColor="#f45d5d"
        android:endColor="#f45d5d"/>
    <size android:height="@dimen/activity_bottom_height_hover"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#f45d5d"/>
</shape>
```

**flat_btn_bt_normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#232323"
        android:centerColor="#232323"
        android:endColor="#232323"/>
    <size android:height="@dimen/activity_bottom_height"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#3e3e3e"/>
</shape>
```

**flat_btn_bt.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/flat_btn_bt_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/flat_btn_bt_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/flat_btn_hover" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/flat_btn_bt_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Then, I set the background for the Button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_btn_bt"/>
```

But when working, it changes the color and don't change size layout.
Can you tell me how to change the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape scales to the size of the container View proportionate to the dimensions defined here, by default.

Remove your size attribute